# MVC Accessing Controller Action Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I currently have a controller with multiple action functions like

```
public ActionResult LogIn(){return View();}
```

They also include signup, account, logout, etc.

I have also created views from all these functions. Why is it that when I put a break point on them, the function bodies are never being accessed? It seems like from page to page, only the Views are being rendered.

Only the first Index action method is being called.

It makes it impossible to create and initialize values in the action methods, then push them to the View when the page is being displayed. I almost feel like the controller action methods are being ignored.

Comment: How are you setting breakpoints? If you have the method defined entirely on one line and are setting breakpoints on that line, it's possible that the breakpoint is set at a point that doesn't trigger when the function is called. If you place the breakpoint specifically on `return View();` does it still fail to trigger?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on whether you're having trouble setting breakpoints on the actions, or whether you feel your actions aren't being called at all.  Can you clarify?

Comment: My actions are not being called at all. I feel like it goes to the view directly because I'm using: <button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Logout","User")';return false;"><Strong>LOG OUT</Strong></button>

Comment: Your views are definitely not being called without the action.  In fact, it's the action that directly calls the view engine.  That's what that `View()` method does.  Have you modified your routes at all, in the RouteConfig.cs file?  Perhaps your routes don't point to the actions you think they do.